# jquery - document.ready getting called after all the images are loaded in iE

Tags: jquery

There was a bug in JQuery 1.3.1 that JQuery is waiting for images to load before executing document.ready in IE alone.I am using jquery-1.4.4.min.js
and having the same pproblem.Is the bug still persists ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no known bug like this in jQuery itself...you have something *else* going on affecting the page load with your specific page, `document.ready` doesn't check images in any way, only that the elements are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such bug in jquery. Are you sure you are not using [window.load](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/)?